# Can we make our program installable in any Linux distro?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu-16.04, centos7, rhel7

Could I install my program in any Linux distro with the simple command like:
Suppose my program name is `manish` So

```
for ubuntu
    `sudo apt-get install manish`
or in centos
    `yum install manish`
```

Comment: What is your question? Have you tried this code? Did it work on "any linux distro"? What problems did you encounter? What help do you need?

Comment: I have build a program on python for ubuntu, now i want to make my program installable on Ubuntu. Like in case of ubuntu if we want to install VLC we type in the terminal 'sudo apt-get install vlc'. else if we want to install FIREFOX we type 'sudo apt-get install firefox' . In the same way I  want to do the same thing so that anyone can install my program.

Comment: You didn't answer my question: Have you tried your code? Did it work? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: I am asking the procedure to do it, I haven't tried any codes cause I don't know where to start from and what to do to make it possible?

Comment: @ManishShah: Package manager `apt` works with repositories and `.deb` files they provide. So, for make your program installable with `apt` you need: 1. Create a `.deb` file which manage installation. 2. Create a repository containing that file. 3. Add this repository to the list of repositories processed with `apt`. In the net there are a lot of manuals for every of these steps. Try to follow them. Would you face with a **specific problem** during that process, you may ask about that problem on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the commands mentioned are supposed to use in case the package is in a repository. The "apt/yum install" command will not work in your case. Anyway you can create your own repository and import it in your /etc/yum.repo.d/ (centos/oraclelinux/RH...) path. The file could be:

```
[<repo tag (your choise)>]
name=<your repo's name>
baseurl=http://<repo's url once you have published it>
gpgkey=file:///<gpg key path (not obligatory)
gpgcheck=0 (if you have not a gpg key)
enabled=1
```

Once enabled you can procede with "yum update" command and verify with "yum repolist" command if the repository works.